# click event on td not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table. In the `td` tag there is a checkbox. If I click on that checkbox then it gets checked or unchecked as usual. But what I want is that If I click anywhere on that specific `td` then the checkbox will also get checked or unchecked. Its because if there are a lot of rows and checkboxes there then you might find it hard to exactly put your mouse pointer over the checkbox and press a click (checkboxes are small so finding it difficult is normal). So I want it to be easy for my client, if he press a click outside the checkbox but inside the parent `td` tag then it will also work.

My JQuery code is working very good. Now if I click outside the checkbox then its click event is triggered. But the problem is now If I click exactly on the checkbox then it is not working. I am giving my code below. Here is also a [`jsfiddle link of my code`](https://jsfiddle.net/sv1b02kd/3/).

```
<div class='modal-inner-content'>
  <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td class='check'><input type='checkbox'/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My JQuery code:

```
$('.modal-inner-content').on('click', 'td', function(){
  var checked = $(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked');
    $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !checked);
});
```

**UPDATE**
Now the jsfiddle code will work, i forgot to include the library. Now see there, if you click outside the checkbox then its working but if you click exactly on the checkbox then its not working. any help?

Comment: its working if i click outside the checkbox. yah thats what i wanted. but now if i click exactly on the checkbox its not working. i didnt want that :)

Comment: oh..okay now i understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.modal-inner-content td').click(function (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).is('input')) {
           $('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked', function (i, value) {
            return !value;
           });
        }
    });
```

Comment: its working now thanks. but can you please explain why its now working and why it wasn't working before?

Comment: the reason was when you was clicking on check-box it self, checked was always returning true ans thats why it was not checking the checkbox

Comment: yes but the event will only trigger if a `td` under `modal-inner-content` div is clicked. So what the checkbox is returning while i click inside it, it should not matter right? i mean the trigger is for that specific `td` not for that checkbox.

Comment: no it will not only trigger when td only will be clicked, it will also be called when you click on checkbox it self :) because checkbox is also the part of td

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by checking the clicked element is checkbox or not like following.

```js
$('.modal-inner-content').on('click', 'td', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(':checkbox')) {
        var checked = $(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked');
        $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !checked);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='modal-inner-content'>
    <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <td class='check'>
                <input type='checkbox' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

in your jsfiddle just add Jquery resource

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js

Comment: that was a bad typo

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the library. but thats not the problem. see now i added the library but it still is not working.

Comment: @WahidMasud you have to click "Run" and "Update" after adding as resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.modal-inner-content').on('click', 'check', function() {
  var checked = $(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked');
    $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !checked);
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!